# Approximate a and b of $y = ae^{bx}$ using the method of least squares

Tags: exponential-function, least-squares

My data are:

```
x 2.2 2.6 3.4 4.0
y 65 61 54 50
```

If I take the logarithm of the given equation, I will get $$\ln y = \ln a + bx$$

How should I use my data from here? Would it be alright if I just plug in the first two sets of x, y values which will give me:

$$\ln 65 = \ln a + 2.2b$$
$$\ln 61 = \ln a + 2.6b$$

and solve these two equations for a and b? How will the method of least squares come into play?

Comment: That's one way to do it. It's not the method of least squares, though.

Comment: I am trying to follow the steps here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingExponential.html which I believe uses the method of least squares but I got stuck at step 5. How did they come up with the formula at step 5? Could someone walk me through this...thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)$ and the model is
$$y=a\,e^{bx}$$ which is nonlinear because of $b$; because of that, you need estimates of the parameters.

Fortunately, in a first step, you can *approximate* the model by linearization taking logarithms
$$\log(y)= \log(a)+ b x= c+b x$$
So, because of the above, for each data point, define $z_i=\log(y_i)$ and you have the linear model
$$z= c+b x$$ and you just need the most basic linear regression which will give you $c$ and $b$ and from $c$, $a=e^c$ but these are *estimates* only of the true parameters.

However, this is not sufficient and you need later to apply nonlinear regression since what has been measured is $y$ and not any of its possible transforms.